# Java: Creating objects with variable type and calling methods on an object with variable name

Tags: java

I have a hashmap with keys of type String and values of type ArrayList.

It looks something like this:

```
key: ".avi", value: {new VideoResource(var), "videoResources"}
```

I want to do the following things:

1.
Create a new variable with the same type as that of the one found in the hashmap. This time I would want to create a new VideoResource, but it could be anything (AudioResource, ImageResource...) depending on what's inside the hashmap. The types always take the same parameter "var", however.

So, I want to do:

```
SomeResource resource = new SomeResource(var);
```

where SomeResource is decided by the type of some object.

2.
Call a method on an object, that is previously instantiated, with the name given by

```
String objectName = hashMap.get(key).get(1);
```

The object will always have the method and the method being called will always have the same name.

So, I want to do:

```
objectName.methodName();
```

where objectName is decided by some string.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT

The context is this:

For an assignment I've been tasked to refactor a bit of code in the open-source project FreeCol. The method I am refactoring is createResource shown below. The problem with it is, that in addition to the very repetitive if-statements, it violates the open/closed principle. We want it to be open for extension, i.e. adding a new extension type (.avi etc.), but closed for modification, i.e. you shouldn't have to modify a whole bunch of code to do so.

The method looks like this:

```
public static void createResource(URI uri, ResourceSink output) {
if(findResource(uri, output))
    return;

try {
    if ("urn".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        if (uri.getSchemeSpecificPart().startsWith(ColorResource.SCHEME)) {
            ColorResource cr = new ColorResource(uri);
            output.add(cr);
            colorResources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(cr));
        } else if (uri.getSchemeSpecificPart().startsWith(FontResource.SCHEME)) {
            FontResource fr = new FontResource(uri);
            output.add(fr);
            fontResources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(fr));
        }
    } else if (uri.getPath().endsWith("\"")
            && uri.getPath().lastIndexOf('"',
                    uri.getPath().length()-1) >= 0) {
        StringResource sr = new StringResource(uri);
        output.add(sr);
        stringResources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(sr));
    } else if (uri.getPath().endsWith(".faf")) {
        FAFileResource far = new FAFileResource(uri);
        output.add(far);
        fafResources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(far));
    } else if (uri.getPath().endsWith(".sza")) {
        SZAResource szr = new SZAResource(uri);
        output.add(szr);
        szaResources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(szr));
    } else if (uri.getPath().endsWith(".ttf")) {
        FontResource fr = new FontResource(uri);
        output.add(fr);
        fontResources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(fr));
    } else if (uri.getPath().endsWith(".wav")) {
        AudioResource ar = new AudioResource(uri);
        output.add(ar);
        audioResources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(ar));
    } else if (uri.getPath().endsWith(".ogg")) {
        if (uri.getPath().endsWith(".video.ogg")) {
            VideoResource vr = new VideoResource(uri);
            output.add(vr);
            videoResources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(vr));
        } else {
            AudioResource ar = new AudioResource(uri);
            output.add(ar);
            audioResources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(ar));
        }
    } else {
        ImageResource ir = new ImageResource(uri);
        output.add(ir);
        imageResources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(ir));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Failed to create resource with URI: " + uri, e);
    }
}
```

So what I want to do, is to get rid of all the else ifs that handle the file extensions, and replace them with a single call to a method assignResource that creates the right resource

```
SomeResource resource = new SomeResource(uri);
```

adds it to the output

```
output.add(resource);
```

and puts it in the right WeakHashMap

```
someResource.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(resource));
```

These hashmaps are declared as following:

```
private static final Map<URI, WeakReference<ColorResource>> colorResources = new WeakHashMap<>();
private static final Map<URI, WeakReference<FontResource>> fontResources = new WeakHashMap<>();
private static final Map<URI, WeakReference<StringResource>> stringResources = new WeakHashMap<>();
private static final Map<URI, WeakReference<FAFileResource>> fafResources = new WeakHashMap<>();
private static final Map<URI, WeakReference<SZAResource>> szaResources = new WeakHashMap<>();
private static final Map<URI, WeakReference<VideoResource>> videoResources = new WeakHashMap<>();
private static final Map<URI, WeakReference<ImageResource>> imageResources = new WeakHashMap<>();
```

I have code that extracts the file extension from the URI, and puts it as a key, along with the associated object (i.e. VideoResource()) and the name of the object upon with we want to invoke the put() method (i.e. "videoResources"), as values.

The idea is that if you would add a new extension type, you just have to do one function call to my method addResource:

```
addResource(resourceMap, ".ogg", new VideoResource(uri), "videoResources");
```

that adds these parameters to the map of file extensions it can handle.

Instead of all the else if statements, a single call to a method assignResource

```
assignResource(uri, resourceMap);
```

would be made.

So the problem I faced was how to create a new object of a type that matches that of the one found in my hashmap, and then invoking method put() on the right WeakHashMap (videoResources etc.).

EDIT

More questions.

The line `output.add(resource);` gives an error because resource is a Resource and not one of the subtypes. The next line, `resources.add(uri, resource);` complains about type safety, that references should be parameterized. I changed the interface to your second suggested generic one. An example of what a Resources implementation now looks like is this:

```
class StringResources implements Resources<StringResource> {

    private final Map<URI, WeakReference<Resource>> resources = new WeakHashMap<>();
    @Override
    public boolean matches(URI uri) {
        return uri.getPath().endsWith("\"")
            && uri.getPath().lastIndexOf('"', uri.getPath().length() - 1) >= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public StringResource from(URI uri) {
        return new StringResource(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(URI uri, StringResource resource) {
        resources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(resource));
    }  
}
```

Is this how you meant they should look? In that case, how should we change the lines

```
Resource resource = resources.from(uri);
output.add(resource);
resources.add(uri, resource);
```

so that the resource is of the right subtype when we call output.add?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the answer for your question but what you're trying to do is most likely not the best solution for whatever problem you have. Providing more context could result in better approach.

```
class VideoResource {

    public VideoResource(Object var) {
    }

    public void videoResources() {
        System.out.println("It was called");
    }
}

class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String key = ".avi";

        Map<String, List<Object>> map = prepareExample(key);

        Class<?> unknownClass = map.get(key).get(0).getClass();

        try {
            // getConstructor accepts class of parameter type
            Constructor<?> constructor = unknownClass.getConstructor(Object.class);
            Object newInstance = constructor.newInstance("abc");
            Method method = newInstance.getClass().getMethod((String) map.get(key).get(1));
            method.invoke(newInstance);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, List<Object>> prepareExample(String key) {
        Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new VideoResource(null));
        list.add("videoResources");
        map.put(key, list);
        return map;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Alright. According to presented context I have a proposition of solution. I would start with creating two interfaces:

```
interface Resource {
}

interface Resources {
    boolean matches(URI uri);
    Resource from(URI uri);
    void add(URI uri, Resource resource);
}
```

I believe there must be some common interface for those resources as ResourceSink class accepts any of them. I didn't create a full solution but you should be able to do it yourself after a while of explanation. Example implementations of both interfaces are presented below for two resources existing in this project:

```
class ColorResource implements Resource {
    ColorResource(URI uri) {
    }
}

class ColorResources implements Resources {

    private final String COLOR_RESOURCE_SCHEMA = "";

    private final Map<URI, WeakReference<Resource>> resources = new WeakHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean matches(URI uri) {
        return uri.getSchemeSpecificPart().startsWith(COLOR_RESOURCE_SCHEMA);
    }

    @Override
    public Resource from(URI uri) {
        return new ColorResource(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(URI uri, Resource resource) {
        resources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(resource));
    }
}

class StringResource implements Resource {
    StringResource(URI uri) {
    }
}

class StringResources implements Resources {

    private final Map<URI, WeakReference<Resource>> resources = new WeakHashMap<>();
    @Override
    public boolean matches(URI uri) {
        return uri.getPath().endsWith("\"")
            && uri.getPath().lastIndexOf('"', uri.getPath().length() - 1) >= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource from(URI uri) {
        return new StringResource(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(URI uri, Resource resource) {
        resources.put(uri, new WeakReference<>(resource));
    }
}
```

As you can see Resources interfaces is able to tell if it should create resource from given uri (matches), create it (from) and store internally (add). It has those WeakHashMap inside. Last thing is changing your main method:

```
class Stack464 {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Stack464.class.toString());

    private static final Resources colorResources = new ColorResources();
    private static final Resources stringResources = new StringResources();

    public static void createResource(URI uri, ResourceSink output) {
        try {
            Stream.of(colorResources,
                      stringResources)
                .filter(resources -> resources.matches(uri))
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(resources -> {
                    Resource resource = resources.from(uri);
                    output.add(resource);
                    resources.add(uri, resource);
                });
        } catch(Exception e){
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Failed to create resource with URI: " + uri, e);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I replaced every map field with field of type Resources. Then in the main method I create a stream from the fields. Then I'm trying to find first match among them - I'm looking for resources class able to create a resource from given uri. Then I take first of them, creating a resource, adding it to Sink and to internal resources map.

Now to add new resource type you need to implement two interfaces, add new field and modify fields inside Stream#of.

There are two things I need to to mention:

1. in your code you could use the resources stored in map and they had proper value type like ColorResources etc. In My solutions
   internal maps must have WeakReference value because they
   produce object of class Resource. So to actually use it you would
   have to cast it (but you can safely do it inside concrete Resources
   implementation).
2. The order of fields in Stream#of matters. In your code you create VideResource when the suffix of uri is ".video.ogg" and
   AudioResource if it is ".ogg". If you would put AudioResources above
   VideoResources in Stream#of then even if it would be a video
   resource the code would create audio resource as suffix ".ogg"
   occured. Placing VideoResources above AudioResources solves the
   problem. So you must order fields in Stream#from from more concrete
   to more general matching patterns.

The first problem could be avoided changing interface Resources to

```
interface Resources<T extends Resource> {
    boolean matches(URI uri);
    T from(URI uri);
    void add(URI uri, T resource);
}
```

Then `class ColorResources implements Resources<ColorResource>` could have inner WeakHashMap with references to ColorResource. It would result in calling Resources#add on raw Resources type as in ifPresent method we don't know which implementation handles it.

**Edit:**

To use overloaded method add of ResourceSink there is only one solution I have on my mind. This is method used in visitor pattern. First of all modify your Resource interface:

```
interface Resource {
    void putIn(ResourceSink resourceSink);
}
```

And now example implementation looks like:

```
class ColorResource implements Resource {
    ColorResource(URI uri) {
    }

    @Override
    public void putIn(ResourceSink resourceSink) {
        resourceSink.add(this);
    }
}
```

Inside the ColorResource `this` has ColorResource type so expected ResourceSink#add method is invoked. Then u change main method to utilize this new function.

```
Resource resource = resources.from(uri);
resource.putIn(output);
resources.add(uri, resource);
```

Now about this unsafe add call on Resources class. If you really need References to concrete classes in hash map then I don't know better approach. If u don't then not using generics solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I wasn't clear enough about the second part. I don't want to invoke a method videoResources(), but rather, I have an object

`private static final Map<key, value> videoResources
        = new WeakHashMap<>();`

(and many others; audioResources, imageResources etc.)
upon which I want to invoke a method, specifically the put() method of HashMap.

I.e. I want to do

`videoResources.put(key, value);`

So in your solution, "method" is not the name of the method I want to invoke, but rather the name of the object I want to call the method put() on. @julian

Comment: The simplest solution I can imagine is having map where key is name of this object and value is object itself.  You would obtain map videoResources calling get("videoResources")  on this map.

Comment: Notice though that your problem is getting more and more strange. Providing broader context might result in better solution.

Comment: I added the full context of my problem. Do you have any ideas of a better solution with the context provided? Thank you. @julian

Comment: @Zebrastian, if it solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Of course. I might try to implement your updated solution, but I have a couple of questions regarding your first solution first. In `Constructor<?> constructor = unknownClass.getConstructor(Object.class);`, is the parameter Object.class because the constructor VideoResource takes an Object? In actuality, the constructor for VideoResource takes a URI, so it would be URI.class? However, when I try this, two unit tests go from failing to giving an error. I have no idea why.

Comment: Another question: The public interface ResourceSink has a bunch of methods add(). void add(VideoResource r); etc for each type. I have `Class<?> resource = (Class<?>)resourceMap.get(extension).get(0);` now instead since I store a class (like class VideoResource) in the arraylist instead. I want to call the add function of ResourceSink for the right class (example VideoResource). I've tried `Method methodAdd = ResourceSink.class.getMethod("add", resource);` Is this the right syntax? I think this might be incorrect.

Comment: 1st question -  yes.  Without your unit test and code I'm not able to check why it fails. 2nd I'm pretty sure searching for the right method you can specify class like videoResources.class

Comment: I've tried your updated solution, and I only have one problem. On the line `output.add(resource)` I get an error because of the first thing you mentioned, but I can't figure out how to cast it inside the concrete resources classes in the way you mentioned. You've been of great help this far. Thank you.

Comment: Create another method in resources getting resource and sink as parameters in cast resource inside concrete resources class like inside StringResources cast to StringResource etc

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but I'm just not getting it. Does the cast method have a return type? Or should it be `void cast(Resource resource, ResourceSink output);`? And in VideoResource, do I override it so that it does `resource = (VideoResource) resource;`? How and where do I call it in the createResource method? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my post with how the current situation looks and what the final problems I have are. It would mean the world to me if you could take a look at it :)

Comment: @Zebrastian does the final solution do what you want?